# 1366 Incorrect integer value error while storing data into the database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel application I have two user roles, admins and general users.

An admin can add data in a general user profiles as well.

In my db table, I have two columns to save user id and the added_by user's id.

If a general user add record to their own profile, both this column should include general user's user id.

But if an admin user did this, then added_by has to be filled with admin's user id.

I'm fetching the general user's user id from the URL.

My function looks like this at the moment (Here, I've included only the related part for this question)

```
$employee_Id=$request->get('emp_id');
if(is_numeric($employee_Id)){
            $employee_Id=$request->get('emp_id');
            $user = User::where('id',$employee_Id);
            $addedBy_User = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
//If the employer tried to add their stats    
}else{
            $user=User::find(auth()->user()->id);
            $employee_Id=$user->id;
            $addedBy_User =User::find(auth()->user()->id);
}
$statsUser = StatsUser::create([
            'stat_id'               => $stat->id,
            'user_id'               => $employee_Id,
            'added_by'              => $addedBy_User,
            
        ]);
```

But this gives me an error saying, `1366 Incorrect integer value` what I'm doing wrong and where should I fix?

The complete error message as follows,

```
1366 Incorrect integer value: '{\"id\":869,\"language\":\"en\",\"first_name\":\"Test\",\"last_name\":\"Name2\",\"email\":\"testmail@gmail.com\",\"email_verified_at\":\"2022-03-...' for column `cricketstats`.`stats_user`.`added_by` at row 1
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message

Comment: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '{\"id\":869,\"language\":\"en\",\"first_name\":\"Test\",\"last_name\":\"Name2\",\"email\":\"testmail@gmail.com\",\"email_verified_at\":\"2022-03-...' for column `cricketstats`.`stats_user`.`added_by` at row 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$addedBy_User` is an object which will get from the database. so you can not assign objects to the table field. so instead of `$addedBy_User` use `$addedBy_User->id`.

```
    $addedBy_User = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
    $statsUser = StatsUser::create([
        'stat_id'               => $stat->id,
        'user_id'               => $employee_Id,
        'added_by'              => $addedBy_User->id,
        
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense since in your `if` statement you are checking if `$employee_Id` is numeric. then look what you have in the  `else` statement:

```php
//...
} else {
    $user=User::find(auth()->user()->id);
    $employee_Id=$user->id;
    $addedBy_User = $employee_Id; // <--
}
```

So, when `$employee_Id` is not numeric then `$addedBy_User` is also not numeric -> not an integer. Hence, the exception is thrown.

Comment: then I changed my code in the else statement to $addedBy_User = User::find(auth()->user()->id); but still gives me the same error.....

Comment: And also from the previous line I'm assigning $employee_Id==$user->id

Comment: @VolkaDimitrev dd() the data you are providing to the create function and you will find specifically what the issue is. I cannot help you more without knowing the actual data

Answer (score -1):

> $addedBy_User = User::find(auth()->user()->id);

> StatsUser::create([
> 'stat_id'               => $stat->id,
> 'user_id'               => $employee_Id,
> 'added_by'              => $addedBy_User,
>
> ]);

$addedBy_User is an object , Solution -> $addedBy_User->id